# How to convert data to log10 while ignoring or removing the values of 0?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The code I'm using:

```
pay3 = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5', 'P6']

logs = np.log10(df[pay3])
```

So my `pay3` variable is a group of 6 columns from my data frame. All of the data are integers. I'm trying to convert the data in those columns to a `log10`, and I also need to ignore the values of `0`.

I can't just drop rows because a given row could have a `0` on only one or two columns. Is this possible to do? I'm going to need to turn this into a histogram for each column after I have the data straightened out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with pandas, but I'm fairly certain you can do this with the following code:

```
logs = [np.log10(df[df[col] != 0][col]) for col in pay3]
```

After this `logs` should be a list of pandas series that you can then do with as you please.